# Cannot open (GPIO) Pin 6 in Windows 10 Iot Core

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, gpio, windows-10-iot-core

I want to let the red LED of my RainbowHAT shine. That requires that I send a high signal to the `BCM 6` pin.

**(Shortend) Source**

Class constant:

```
private static readonly int GPIO_NUMBER_RED = 22;
```

Called in the constructor:

```
    var gpioController = GpioController.GetDefault();

    redPin = gpioController.OpenPin(GPIO_NUMBER_RED);
    redPin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    redPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
```

I tried the values 6 (BCM), 31 (Pin number) and 22 (Wiring pin number) for my class global constant `GPIO_NUMBER_RED` but I get always the error:

```
    WinRT information: Pin ' is not available. It is reserved by the system or in use for another function.
```

**Pin layout**

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/rainbow_hat

**Full source**

[GitHub](https://github.com/tscholze/dotnet-iot-homebear-rainbow/blob/master/HomeBear.Rainbow/Controller/RainbowHAT.cs)

**Package Info**

```
    <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
        <DeviceCapability Name="lowLevel"/>
    </Capabilities>
```

I also restarted the Pi to "reset" maybe other application that access this Pin - without success.

Comment: Is GPIO_NUMBER_RED a local variable? If so can we see any lines which set the value of "GPIO_NUMBER_RED"

Comment: @Jamesm It's a class constant. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution #2**

After @michaelxu-msft pointed out, that I miss used the `Singelton` pattern, I removed it and voila, now I can call the Init from my Constructor. I've to research why.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

If do not call the `gpioController` in the Constructor but in another method that will be called after the Init, everything works fine.

Now, the question is, why is it not possible to do it in the init?

Comment: Have you referred to this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/HelloBlinky)? The `gpioController` is initialized in the constructor of the page. So i think your problem is not relative to that. Could you please provide more codes? If possible, you can provide the project.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT yes I did. My question was meant as "would could I have done probably wrong". This is the source class. Please have a look at the `Init()` method below the constructor.

https://github.com/tscholze/dotnet-iot-homebear-rainbow/blob/master/HomeBear.Rainbow/Controller/RainbowHAT.cs

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the repo and view the code. I'm not sure why you need to add the Init method in the constructor in MainPageViewModel. But it is not recommended to add the singleton instance in the constructor method of the model, since the model is used to bind to view to show the data. When you reuse the GPIO pin resource, you should release and dispose it in another page. In addition, GpioPin should be disposed manually when you needn't to use. You may try to move the Init method in the constructor of RainbowHAT, like following code.

**RainbowHAT.cs(Update)**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Private singelton instance.
    /// </summary>
    private static RainbowHAT instance;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default instance of RainbowHAT.
    /// </summary>
    public static RainbowHAT Default
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new RainbowHAT();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private RainbowHAT()
    {
        gpioController = GpioController.GetDefault();

        // Ensure that we have a valid gpio connection
        if (gpioController == null)
        {
            throw new OperationCanceledException("Operation canceled due missing GPIO controller");
        }

        Init();
    }


    public void PerformAction(RainbowHATAction action)
    {
        switch(action)
        {
            case RainbowHATAction.TurnOnRed:
                redPin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
                break;

            case RainbowHATAction.TurnOffRed:
                redPin.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
                break;

            case RainbowHATAction.LEDsOn:
                apa102.TurnOn();
                break;

            case RainbowHATAction.LEDsOff:
                apa102.TurnOff();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        // Setup timer.
        ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer
            (ClockTimer_Tick,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
       );

        // Setup callback
        rainbowHAT.CaptiveButtonPressed += CaptiveButtonPressed;
    }
```

Comment: This was my first approach ever. But no, I'll get an `WinRT information: Pin ' is not available. It is reserved by the system or in use for another function.` exception.

Do you mean, that I should not use the Singelton Pattern at all?

Comment: @Tobonaut, Singelton Pattern can be used for RainbowHAT class. But it seems that in your code it is not available for GpioController. I have modified it and it works fine.